# I want to convert my C program to MIPS instruction

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, mips

I would like to know if its possible to get this code to convert to MIPS using gcc in ubuntu 11.04. 
I tried lcc but was not able to make it to install.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fibnacci(int c)
{
if(c==0)
return 0;
else if(c==1)
return 1;
else
return (fibnacci(c-1)+fibnacci(c-2));
}
int main(){
int i;
printf("Enter the fib number");
scanf("%d",&i);
int a;
a= fibnacci(i);
printf("The value is %d",a);
}
```

Comment: What happened? What was your compile command? Can you give the errors you saw?

Comment: the make of LCC gave this error:
    root@ubuntu:/home/lincon/Desktop/lcc# make all
    cc -g -c -o /host.o 
    cc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [/host.o] Error 4

Comment: Can this be compiled in gcc to get MIPS code?

Comment: What is in your makefile?

Comment: Maybe start with a different question: can you compile "anything" - even "hello world"?

Comment: well supposedly host.o should have come in the directory but it is not created. Any idea what was wrong in lcc make file which is not creating this host.o?

Comment: well I can use gcc to compile.. but I want to run on lcc.

Comment: what happens when you don't use `make all` but type the compile command explicitly - i.e. file names, options, everything?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to generate mips code, GCC must be configured as cross-compiler with `mips` as target architecture. So correct answer -- no you can't do it with regular `gcc` in Ubuntu. You must get mips cross-compiler. To get it, install `embedian` package from package manager and use `gcc-4.4-mips-linux-gnu` or install mips cross-compiler from sources.

Comment: Alternatively, MIPS points at several cross-compilers here: http://developer.mips.com/tools/compilers/.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile. Slight change compiles to MIPS on my Ubuntu with a MIPS simulator.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fibnacci(int c)
{
if(c==0)
return 0;
else if(c==1)
return 1;
else
return (fibnacci(c-1)+fibnacci(c-2));
}
int main(){
int i;
int a;
printf("Enter the fib number");
scanf("%d",&i);
a= fibnacci(i);
printf("The value is %d",a);
}
```

The assembly is

```
    .file   1 "mips-c.c"

 # -G value = 8, Cpu = 3000, ISA = 1
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  fibnacci
    .ent    fibnacci
fibnacci:
    .frame  $fp,32,$31      # vars= 0, regs= 3/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0010000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw  $31,24($sp)
    sw  $fp,20($sp)
    sw  $16,16($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,32($fp)
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    bne $2,$0,$L2
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L1
    j   $L3
$L2:
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    li  $3,1            # 0x00000001
    bne $2,$3,$L4
    li  $2,1            # 0x00000001
    j   $L1
    j   $L5
$L4:
    lw  $3,32($fp)
    addu    $2,$3,-1
    move    $4,$2
    jal fibnacci
    move    $16,$2
    lw  $3,32($fp)
    addu    $2,$3,-2
    move    $4,$2
    jal fibnacci
    addu    $3,$16,$2
    move    $2,$3
    j   $L1
$L5:
$L3:
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,24($sp)
    lw  $fp,20($sp)
    lw  $16,16($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    fibnacci
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "Enter the fib number\000"
    .sdata
    .align  2
$LC1:
    .ascii  "%d\000"
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC2:
    .ascii  "The value is %d\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,32,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    sw  $fp,24($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    jal __main
    la  $4,$LC0
    jal printf
    la  $4,$LC1
    addu    $5,$fp,16
    jal scanf
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal fibnacci
    sw  $2,20($fp)
    la  $4,$LC2
    lw  $5,20($fp)
    jal printf
$L6:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $fp,24($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    main
```